# Using day of the week in where statement

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql, dayofweek

Using HIVE SQL, I currently have a query that runs every Sunday using the following statement,

```
Select * from tableA
where date between date_add(current_date, -7) and date_Add(current_Date, -1)
```

If something happens and this code has to be run on Monday I have to manually change the date add to -8 and -2.  Is there a way to have it run from the previous Sunday to the previous Saturday, so I don't have to manually change the numbers every time I run it.

Comment: is this Microsoft SQL server? MySql, Oracle? SQLite?

Comment: @AhmadI apologize. I updated the original post to advise I was using HIVE SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous Sunday is:    `next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'SUN')`

Previous Saturday is:  `next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'SAT')`

I guess you need Sunday week before (subtract -14)

```
Select * from tableA
  where date between next_day(date_sub(current_date, 14), 'SUN') 
         and next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'SAT')
```

If executed today (2021-04-28) it gives 2021-04-18 (Sunday) and 2021-04-24 (Sat)

If executed 2021-04-26(Monday), it gives the same 2021-04-18 (Sunday) and 2021-04-24 (Sat)

This will work the same if executed on any day in current week except last day Saturday (2021-05-01). If executed on Saturday it will pick 2021-05-01 as end date and 2021-04-18 as start date.

If you need this also work correctly if executed on Saturday 2021-05-01 also,
you can calculate start date as `date_sub(next_day(date_sub(current_date, 7), 'SAT'),6)` (Saturday minus 6)

Comment: Will this work on a Monday to grab the Sunday of the week before(8 days ago) and not the day before Sunday(1 day back)?